# <a4j:include> content doesn't get change

Tags: jsf, richfaces, ajax4jsf

This is what i want to achieve. I have navigation panel on left and content panel on right. 
when user click links on left navigation panel , ajax calls made and content panel got rendered. With current implementation, content got change based on the link i clicked. 
however i found content still don't get change when perform following steps:


1. click "display user", user list got display

2. click "add user" to add one user

3. click "display user", user list got display but content is same as the one in step 1.

i am sure data has been inserted into db. 
looks like this  view got cached on server. is there anyway to solve this issue?

following are my code  and screenshot.

thank you,

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

i found answer from this link.
basically, use following line to destroy backing-bean, then problem solved. 
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestMap().remove("wizardBean");

http://java.dzone.com/articles/jboss-richfaces-spring?page=0,6